# Cron jobs in Ubuntu

Tags: cron

How to run a cron job in ubuntu in such a way that it should initiate a python script?

Please explain with a small example.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Although your question does not seem to belong on this site, fret not for there is a [stackexchange](http://superuser.com) site for such questions! You may receive more answers regarding this area of questioning, on a non-[programming specific stackexchange](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) site.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a simple line to run from x to x time:

**e.g.,**

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * ~/py/my_python_script.py
```

*runs every 10 minuts*

**STEP BY STEP USING VIM AS THE SELECTED EDITOR**

1. At your terminal, run: `sudo crontab -e`
2. Afterwards, choose you favorite editor (e.g., vim)
3. type `:i` and hit `enter` to insert a new line
4. Past or write the cronjob line `0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * ~/py/my_python_script.py` and hit `enter` and then `return` to exit that line
5. type `:w` and hit `enter`, to write the file
6. type `:q` and hit `enter` to exit

**Description for the asterisks:**

```
minute (0-59), hour (0-23, 0 = midnight), day (1-31), month (1-12), weekday (0-6, 0 = Sunday), command
```

## In-deep:

To read a more detailed process on how it all works:

[CronHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

[VIM Commands Cheat Sheet](http://bullium.com/support/vim.html)

Comment: Can you please explain in detail? What i mean is that where we should mention the cron job and how to initiate it etc..

Comment: @Sasikiran Vaddi, Added a step by step instruction using the VIM editor.

Comment: Following is the procedure which i have followed                           
1) crontab -e 
   It prompts like this
Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
  1. /bin/ed
  2. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  3. /usr/bin/vim.basic
  4. /usr/bin/vim.tiny
I had choosed the second option and then 
i placed the 
line 1 * * * * /root/test.py

/root/test.py is file where i wrote the script

Answer (score 0):

You can run Crontab in Ubuntu.
Simply just copy and paste the following script in the terminal.

```
crontab -e
```

There you can write command for run your python script, that will execute the program in a specific time interval.

```
* * * * *   python   </path/to/the/file>
```

You can refer the [link](https://crontab.guru/) for the time interval

You can check the log file here

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```