# execute a python program at a periodic interval in django

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a python program which actually update a database. i want to execute that python code automatically once in a day in order to update the DB.
I am using- python-2.7, ubuntu 12.04 and django 1.5.1

Please let me know if is there anything exist for ubuntu 12.04 so that i can do that??

```
url = settings.CURRENCY_FETCH_BASE_URL % to_currency
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

response_str = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().decode(u'utf-8', u'ignore')
```

and insert into DB--

```
info = Currency(country=cntry, name=name, code=currency, value=rate)
```

Comment: You want to take a look at `cron`.

Comment: Check out django_cron, at https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron  It allows for simple cron jobs to be set up in django, and it logs the status of them as well.  Then you set up a normal cron job to run all the crons that you have.  It includes email notifications on failure if you need that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best i found for this problem is to use celery beat. Very easy to use and highly efficient. Please refer to -

http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2010/07/09/djangocelery-quickstart-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-using-cron-and-love-celery.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10720593/1681480) or elsewhere under `crontab`. Rather than doing the timing in python, you will use the shell program `cron` to call your script. For once a day, your time at the beginning of the line would be something like `0 23 * * *` to run it every day at 11PM.